# How to override exception of createUserWithEmailAndPassword method?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase and I'm using a method to create an account for users which called "createUserWithEmailAndPassword".

I found in Firebase [references](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth#exceptions) that one of this method exceptions is "FirebaseAuthWeakPasswordException" which called when the password is less than 6 characters.

I want to catch this exception and show the user a message with my own words,
but when I wrap the method with try&catch I get this error: "**Exception 'com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthWeakPasswordException' is never thrown in the corresponding try block**". 
I tried to fix this for a while, but no luck.
here is a snippet of the code, hope you can help my figure this out:

```
mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {

                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    //   Log.d(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                    // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                    // signed in user can be handled in the listener.

                    if(task.isSuccessful())
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Account has created!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "failed!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***You have not added any FailureListener that's why you can't get correct error code or exception.***

Add it to **mAuth** like this

```
mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass)
      .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        if (e instanceof FirebaseAuthException) {
                            ((FirebaseAuthException) e).getErrorCode());
                           //your other logic goes here
                      }
                    }
                })
```

Do let me know if it changes anything for you.

Comment: Thank you so much!
it's working now, and I just change "e instanceof" to each possible exception, exactly like the reference link in my question: 
FirebaseAuthWeakPasswordException,FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException and FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException.

Comment: Glad it did :) . Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `task.getException()` and then use `instanceof`:

```
mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword("qbix@gmail.com", "only5")
    .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            Log.i(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.w(TAG, "onComplete: Failed=" + task.getException().getMessage());
                if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthWeakPasswordException) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Weak Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I also appreciate your approach. Quite informative for me.

Comment: yeah, it's another good way to solve it, thank you.
I also tried "task.getException().getMessage()" before posting, which gives the build-in error message, the way to use "instanceof" didn't cross my mind.